# Which data structure supports given operations efficiently

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization, data-structures, memory-efficient

I need to think of a data structure, which supports the following operations efficiently:
1) Add an integer x
2) Delete an integer with maximum frequency (if there are more than one element with the same maximum frequency delete all of them).
I am thinking of implementing a segment tree where each node stores the index of its child having largest frequency.
Any ideas or suggestions on how to approach this problem or how should it be implemented would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Why not code them all (list, vector, tree, map), test them, and then get the best one? One factor that may change the efficiency is the size of the container (due to CPU cache limit)

Comment: @Ripi2: That sounds like an awful lot of work, especially if you consider that the ideal structure might not be one of the standard structures, or might involve some combination of the more standard structures.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior No, not that lot of work. Yes, ideal structure may be a hand-fitted one. I suggested those tests because some one asking such this question has not a good feeling with standards yet and this is a good chance to improve his skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a combination of data structures. A hash_map to maintain the frequency mappings, where the key is the integer, and value a pointer to a "frequency" node representing the frequency value and the set of integers having the same frequency. The frequency nodes will be maintained in a list ordered by the values of the frequencies.

The Frequency node can be defined as

```
class Freq {
   int frequency;
   Set<Integer> values_with_frequency;
   Freq prev;
   Freq next;
}
```

The elements HashMap would then contain entries of the form

`Entry<Integer, Freq>`

So, for a snapshot of the dataset such as
`a,b,c,b,d,d,a,e,a,f,b` where the letters denote integers, the following would be how the data structure would look like.

```
c -----> (1, [c, e, f])
    |
    |
e --
    |
    |
f --

a -----> (3, [a, b])
    |
    |
b --

d --> (2, [d])
```

The Freq nodes would be maintained in a linked list, say `freq_nodes`, **sorted** by the frequency value. Note that, as explained below, there wouldn't be any log(n) operation needed for keeping the list sorted on the add/delete operations.

The way the  `add(x)`, and  `delete_max_freq()` operations could be implemented is as follows

**add**(x) :
If x is not found in the `elements` map, check if the first element of the  `freq_nodes` contains the Freq object with frequency 1. If so, add x to the `values_with_frequency` set of the Freq object. Otherwise, create a new Freq object with 1 as the frequency value and x added to the (now only single element) wrapped set `values_with_frequency`

Otherwise, (i.e. if x is already there in the `elements` map), follow the pointer in the value of the entry corresponding to x in elements to the Freq object in the `freq_nodes`, remove x from the `values_with_frequency` field of the Freq object, noting the current value of x’s frequency which is the value of `elements.get(x).frequency`(Hold this value in say F). If the set `values_with_frequency` is rendered empty due to this removal, delete the corresponding node from the `freq_nodes` linked list. Finally if the next Freq node in the `freq_nodes` linked list has the frequency F+1, just add x to the `values_with_frequency` field of the next node. Otherwise just create a Freq node as was done in the case of non-existence of Freq node with frequency 1 above.

Finally, add the entry `(x, Freq)` to the `elements` map.
Note that this whole add(x) operation is going to be O(1) in time.

Here's an example of a sequence of **add()** operations with the subsequent state of the data structure.

**add(a)**

```
a -> N1 :       freq_nodes :   |N1 (1,  {a}) |   ( N1 is actually a Freq object)
```

**add(b)**

```
a -> N1 :        freq_nodes :   |N1 (1,  {a, b}) | 
b -> N1
```

**add**(a)
At this point ‘a’ points to N1, however, its current frequency is 2, so we need to insert a node N2 next to N1 in the DLL, after removing it from N1’s `values_with_frequency` set {a,b}

```
a -> N2 :       freq_nodes :   |N1 (1,  {b}) |  --> |N2 (2,  {a}) | 
b -> N1
```

The interesting thing to note here is that any time we increase the frequency of an existing element from F  to say F+1, we need to do the following

````
if (next node has a higher frequency than F+1 or we have reached the end of the list):

     create a new Freq node with frequency equal to F+1 (as is done above) 
     and insert it next to the current node
else :
    add ‘a’ (the input to the add() operation) to the ```values_with_frequency``` set of the next node
````

The **delete_max_freq**() operation would just involve removing the last entry of the linked list `freq_nodes`, and iterating over the keys in the wrapped set `values_with_frequency` to remove the corresponding keys from the `elements` map. This operation would take O(k) time where k is the number of elements with maximum frequency.

Comment: “remove x from the `values_with_frequency`” → This seems `O(n)`. You could solve this by making the hash map including the index, and being careful with how you handle deletion. This is a neat data structure-y way of tackling the problem, but in practice I'd recommend less pointer-heavy code

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I initially thought about maintaining the ``` values_with_frequency ``` as a set, but for some reason dropped it. Will make the edit. And yeah, in practice, a less pointer heavy code makes sense.

Comment: Remember that _finding_ a given node in a linked list (which I think is implied in the "add" step) is `O(n)`. You could get around that by having your hashmap's entry's _value_ be a node in the linked list. I think with that one modification I think your claims regarding complexity would all be true, making this option scale much better than mine. If you make that change (or explain why I'm wrong), you'll get my vote.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @StriplingWarrior. Note that the "elements" in which the input integer x is being looked for is a HashMap. The entries in the "elements" map , as described in my post, are entries of the form (x, Freq). So, the initial lookup of x during the add() operation is happening in this HashMap. 

Now, all these Freq objects are further arranged in a linked list, but at no point is the list being scanned linearly, so there wouldn’t be any O(n) time consumed during add. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I understood all of that before, but I disagree with your the last sentence. Your solution says "delete the corresponding node" and "if the next Freq node", which implies that you have access to the node pointers. But your HashMap is not storing nodes: it's storing `Freq`s. So you either need to give `Freq` `next` and `previous` properties to allow it to serve as both the value and a node in the linked list, or you need to make your HashMap store a linked list node which in turn stores a `Freq`. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's exactly my point @StriplingWarrior. Sorry if it was not clear. Freq is indeed a node to be used in the list. I didn’t go into the implementation details, but the freq_nodes list should be implemented as a doubly linked list (DLL) and a handle to this underlying list would be available at the main data structure that would wrap the HashMap and this list. I’ll edit the Freq with the next, previous links to make it look more implementation ready. I'll also add an example.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "efficient" refers to the way the complexity of those operations scale, big-O style, I'd consider something consisting of:

- a hashmap with the integers as keys and their frequencies as values
- a tree structure (possibly a binary search tree, e.g.) where its nodes have a number representing a frequency and a hashset of numbers which have that frequency.

When a number is inserted:
1. Look up the number in the hashmap to find its frequency. (`O(1)`)
2. Look up the frequency in the tree (`O(log N)`). Remove the number from its collection (`O(1)`). If the collection is empty, remove the frequency from the tree (`O(log N)`).
3. Increment the number's frequency. Set that value in the hashmap (`O(1)`).
4. Look up its new frequency in the tree (`O(log N)`). If it's there, add the number to the collection there (`O(1)`). If not, add a new node with the number in its collection (`O(log N)`).

When deleting items with the maximum frequency:
1. Remove the highest-valued node from the tree (`O(log N)`).
2. For each number in that node's collection, remove that number's entry from the hashmap (`O(1)` for each number removed).

If you have N numbers to add and remove, your worst-case scenario should be `O(N log N)` regardless of the actual distribution of frequencies or the order in which numbers are added and removed.

If you know of any assumptions you can make about the numbers being added, it's possible you could make further enhancements like using an indexed array rather than an ordered tree. But if your inputs are fairly unbounded, this seems like a pretty good structure to handle all the operations you want without getting into `O(n²)` territory.

Comment: There is no O(n²) risk from using an indexed array, since the maximum frequency will always be bounded by the number of elements. It does mean that you might use O(n) space when you don't have to, though.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean to imply that an indexed array would enter that realm, though I can see why you could understand what I said that way. The problem with an indexed array is that if you don't know the upper limit to the number of possible frequencies, you can't know how big to make the array. My `O(n²)` comment was just referring to the fact that the general strategy I mentioned avoids exceeding `O(n log n)`, which I think is the best you can hope for given the use case.

Comment: You just need to dynamically size it. You have to do the same thing for sets.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's a great point, since the index only increases as the number of items increase.

Answer (score 2):

**My thoughts:**

- You will need 2 maps.
- Map 1: Integer as key with frequency as value.
- Map 2: Have a map of frequencies as keys and list of integers as values.
- Add Integer: Add the integer to map 1. Get the frequency. Add it to the list of frequency key in map 2.
- Delete Integer : We can obviously maintain maximum frequency in a variable across these operations. Now, remove the key from map2 which has this max frequency and decrement max frequency.
- So, adding and deleting performance should be O(1) on average.

---

In the above scenario, we will still have integers in map 1 which exist and have the frequency which is unrealistic after the delete from map 2. In this case, when same integer gets added, we do an on demand update in map 1, meaning, if current frequency in map 1 doesn't exist in map 2 for this integer, it means it was deleted and we can reset that to 1 again.

---

**Implementation:**

```
import java.util.*;
class Foo{
    Map<Integer,Integer> map1;
    Map<Integer,Set<Integer>> map2;
    int max_freq;
    Foo(){
        map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put(0,new HashSet<>());
        max_freq = 0;
    }


    public void add(int x){
        map1.putIfAbsent(x,0);
        int curr_f = map1.get(x);
        if(!map2.containsKey(curr_f)){
            map1.put(x,1);
        }else{
            map1.merge(x,1,Integer::sum);
        }

        map2.putIfAbsent(map1.get(x),new HashSet<>());
        map2.get(map1.get(x)-1).remove(x); // remove from previous frequency list
        map2.get(map1.get(x)).add(x);// add to current frequency list
        max_freq = Math.max(max_freq,map1.get(x));
        printState();
    }

    public List<Integer> delete(){
        List<Integer> ls = new ArrayList<>(map2.get(max_freq));
        map2.remove(max_freq);
        max_freq--;
        while(max_freq > 0 && map2.get(max_freq).size() == 0) max_freq--;
        printState();
        return ls;
    }

    public void printState(){
        System.out.println(map1.toString());
        System.out.println("Maximum frequency: " + max_freq);
        for(Map.Entry<Integer,Set<Integer>> m : map2.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(m.getKey() + " " + m.getValue().toString());
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
    }

}
```

**Demo:** https://ideone.com/tETHKV

**Note:** The call to `delete()` is amortized.

Comment: If you assume that operation #2 (deleting the maximum frequency integers) has to happen multiple times, you not only need to "maintain maximum frequency," but you need to maintain all of the frequencies, in order of their frequency, right?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Yes, kinda. It's like a carry forward. When frequency of `x` goes from `1` to `2`, it is also moved from the map 2's key of `1` to map 2's key of `2`'s list.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I have added the implementation. Let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: The assumption that `max_freq--` will always yield the next-lowest frequency is incorrect. If you insert values `[1, 2, 2, 2]` and then call `delete()` twice, the call to `map2.remove(max_freq)` will pass a value of `2` in as `max_freq`, but there will be no entries in that map with that frequency.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Nice catch. I have made an update. Now, the call to `delete()` is amortized.

Comment: That's acceptable: it could end up doing a lot of unnecessary work if you have a high frequency of one particular number. But the overall work of adding and subtracting all the values is still `O(n)`, which is great. From a stylistic standpoint, a `do/while` would avoid duplicating the `max_freq--` code.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I was thinking of using a TreeMap to improve the efficiency of updating `max_freq` when we delete the maximum frequency elements.

Comment: That would be fairly similar to the approach I suggested, which requires `O(log n)` operations to maintain the tree's order. I actually really like eternal_learner's idea to have the values of the original hashmap represent nodes in a linked list, since you know an item's frequency will only ever increase by 1 at a time. That way the add operations are `O(1)`, the delete operation is `O(k)` (where k is the number of items with the top frequency), and the overall cost of adding and removing N items becomes `O(N)`, without requiring any unnecessary looping.